# Error received when trying to install library 'pycld2' on Windows 10

Tags: python, polyglot

Trying to install pycld2 (need it for polyglot) and I receive the following error:

> [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Looking for a solution if someone else faced same issue. Thank you!

```
D:\USER\Projects_Python\Sentiment_analysis\pycld2>setup.py install
C:\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.5
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\pycld2
copying pycld2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\pycld2
running build_ext
building 'pycld2._pycld2' extension
**error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing this through anaconda or pip? It's unclear exactly what you're doing here. Are you trying to install this from source?

Comment: Yes, there is. I follow the install instructions from https://pypi.org/project/pycld2/. Initially, I tried also with pip but neither this option is working. $ git clone http://github.com/abosamoor/pycld2.git
$ cd pycld2
$ ./setup.py install

Comment: There's no need to install from source. You can simply run `python -m pip install pycld2`.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to install with pip? Is it the same error?

Comment: I just solved the problem. Downloaded the wheel and I pip installed locally. The initial pip error was: ' Failed building wheel for pycld2'

Comment: Yes. Downloaded locally from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycld2 the pycld2 wheel and than I installed it from local directory with pip install: pip install name_of_wheel.whl